# import from typing within TYPE_CHECKING block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

Does it make sense to import from `typing` inside a `TYPE_CHECKING` block?

Is this good/bad or does it even matter?

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Protocol, runtime_checkable

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing import Any, Callable, Generator
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `typing` is a built-in module and you are already importing it to use `TYPE_CHECKING` anyway, the answer is no, it does not make much sense.

Also, it will only work if all of the usages of imported classes are within quotes (for lazy evaluation). Otherwise you will get a `NameError` when the code runs:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing import List

li: List = []
```

results with

```py
NameError: name 'List' is not defined
```

as opposed to

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing import List

li: 'List' = []
```

which works.

Comment: That's what I figured too.  Is there a downside to doing that, which I might be over looking?

Comment: Yes, it might actually break your code. I updated my answer.

Comment: I believe using `from __future__ import annotations` solves that problem, no?

Comment: @MarcelWilson It does, but then you have 1 more import anyway :)

Comment: I found myself using it everywhere purely because I dislike having to use string annotations.  But back to the main question -- I couldn't find a downside or upside importing from typing either way.  I felt like I might be missing some good reason to do one over the other.  But it sounds like it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @MarcelWilson there's absolutely no reason to import from `typing` in `if TYPE_CHECKING`, since you have already imported `typing` to get `TYPE_CHECKING` in scope, you won't save any import time and will just clutter imports instead. As a good rule of thumb, I import in the `if TYPE_CHECKING` block only from modules which will be not imported otherwise (so e.g. if you `import numpy.typing as npt` but don't have `numpy` in scope, it's a perfect target) or to break import cycles (then runtime imports will go to function/method bodies).